# Is BPMN 2.0 Turing complete?

Tags: bpmn, turing-complete

I am starting a new project with BPMN 2.0. Is the language Turing complete?
At first sight I would say than it is, but I have found some discussions (e.g., https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/Q1fql6BxYpg) in which it is mentioned that it is not. However, I am not sure about how correct are those claims.

One of my main motivations for asking this question is that
workflow engines supporting BPMN 2.0 allow the inclusion of scripting activities (e.g., using a Turing complete language like Groovy). I am wondering if the only objective of this is to allow process-engineers to implement simple customization of a business process, or if the scripting language is also supposed to cover expressiveness issues of BPMN 2.0 ?

Comment: `It is not and never will be compilable (= turing completeness)` Compilable != turing complete. That source seems to be confused. Compilable itself is undefined as a term. Turing complete means that you can use BPM to specify a turing machine (simulator) which appears to be the case.

Comment: Not sure if that is a typo, since below that line it says: " If you design a process in BPMN 2.0 you always need some IT-guy / programmer, to annotated technical details. The need for annotation is in some part caused by the non turing completeness. This is closely related to the problem, that one BPMN operation can have multiple interpretations (thats why BPMN 2.0 is not turing complete)."

Answer (score 1):

Does BPMN have loops and conditions? Probably it has since business processes need that. Then it is Turing complete.

Scripting tasks seem necessary because BPMN is a horrible general purpose programming language. It is made for a specific purpose.

Also for reuse of existing libraries and code end external side effects (sending mail, etc.).

Comment: Indeed a horrible general-purpose programming language. My question was rather to make the distinction between "you cannot" vs "you should not". You seem to imply that the main reason of BPMN engines  supporting a scripting language is clarity? I am just trying to understand if I was missing something else.

Comment: Clarity, reuse of existing libraries and code, external side effects (sending mail, etc.). I should have said that right away.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It clarifies my question. I found a link to a discussion where it is mentioned that BPMN is not Turing complete. Please see the update to my question and let me know if you have further comments. They are appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: A language is Turing complete if it can simulate any Turing machine, this is not directly related with loops. It is easy to define a language that has only terminating loops.

Comment: As far as I remember, static loops where the number of iteration is known beforehand is not enough.

Comment: Yes, true. But why would the number of iterations be limited? Business processes are not limited like that.

Comment: @usr: I know, it was a comment to a comment above mine, not your answer. Sorry to confuse you.